# Reponsive menu using Javascript, issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, menu, responsive-design

When I click on the top bar button I'd like to show my menu but it doens't work...

My JS code :

```
var topBarToggle = document.getElementById('top-bar-toggle');
var topBarUl = document.getElementById('top-bar-ul');

topBarToggle.addEventListener('click', onClickOnTopBarToggle, false);

function onClickOnTopBarToggle(e){
    topBarUl.style.display = topBarUl.style.display === 'none' ? '' : 'none';
}
```

My CSS code :

```
@media screen and (max-width : $container-width){
    ul#top-bar-ul{
        display: none;
    }
}
```

When I click on the button, nothing happens, I don't have any errors... But the `<ul>` don't get the `display:block` property...

**Edit #1:**

```
var topBarToggle = document.getElementById('top-bar-toggle');
var topBarUl = document.getElementById('top-bar-ul');

topBarToggle.addEventListener('click', onClickOnTopBarToggle, false);

function onClickOnTopBarToggle(e){

    console.log(topBarUl.style.display);

    topBarUl.style.display = topBarUl.style.display === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
}
```

Logs :

```
       main.js:101
none   main.js:101
block  main.js:101
none   main.js:101
block  main.js:101
none   main.js:101
```

Comment: `? '' : 'none'` should be `? 'block' : 'none'`.

Comment: No that's not the issue... I suppose that the problem is the CSS property put in my CSS code, Javascript is maybe not able to delete her...

Comment: That is the problem, by not setting anything, the css rule comes to work, you have to overwrite it inline with "block", or whatever this element should be: "inline", "inline-block", "table" etc...

Comment: See edit #1... It doesn't work the first time...

Comment: first time its no "none" on it, so just set it on init to "none" manually...

Comment: first time, topBarUl.style.display is not set. Therefore topBarUl.style.display==='none'  equals false. And it is set to 'none'. So then it is not displayed. -> set it before your code gets executed (init or in page)

Comment: Yes but if I set the `topBarUl.style.display` to `none`, my top bar will be hidden on pc and mobile, and I'd like to hide her only on mobile...

Comment: then you have to set css class, and you could also use jQuery for this.. you tagged it, so you might consider to use it.. `.toggleClass("hide")` for example...

Comment: Ok, so I finally made the decision to use jQuery... And it works with jQuery. But I wanted to not use jQuery because my project is a Front-End framework and I'd like to not have external libraries in "index.html"...

Answer (score 0):

in jQuery something like this:

```
$("#top-bar-toggle").on("click", function(){
    $("#top-bar-ul").toggleClass("showMobile");
});

@media screen and (max-width : $container-width){
    ul#top-bar-ul{
        display: none;
    }
    ul#top-bar-ul.showMobile{
        display: block;
    }
}
```